# How to correctly handle events from Google Map in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-hooks

I am using Google Map API in my React (using hooks) app.

There is Google Map Places & Maps API being used. The user can search for a place, upon selection from dropdown, the map focuses on the location. Or the user can drag/zoom the map to get the location.

**Code Explanation:**

In the code below, when the user selects from dropdown, I save the boundbox (NE & SW co-ordinates) in parent component's (not shown here) state. This triggers updated props to this component which updates the map.

The following code works fine as long as I donot append the listener for `zoom-changed` because the the listener for `drag-end` & search input do not conflict with each other. However, I want to add the zoom functionality as well and this get triggered upon search selection & the app goes into an infinite update look.

**Code:**

```
const ModalGoogleMap = ({ locationSearch, saveLocationSearch, toggleMapModal }) => {
  const defaultCenter = { lat: 51.509865, lng: -0.118092 }
  const defaultZoom = 9;
  const mapDimensions = { width: 900, height: 508 };
  const [gMap, setGMap] = useState();
  const { register } = useForm();
  const searchInputRef = useRef();
  let mapContainerRef = useRef();
  const { address, boundBox } = locationSearch;
  let getPlaces: any;

  useEffect(() => {
    initMap();
    initSearchInput();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (boundBox) {
      const { sw, ne } = boundBox;
      const latlng = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
      gMap.fitBounds(latlng, 0);
    }
  }, [boundBox]);

  const initMap = () => {
    const gMap = new google.maps.Map(
      mapContainerRef.current,
      {
        zoom: defaultZoom,
        center: defaultCenter
      });
    gMap.addListener("dragend", () => mapEvHandler(gMap));
    // zoom-changed listener is triggered everytime a user searches & selects from search-input 
    gMap.addListener("zoom_changed", () => mapEvHandler(gMap));
    setGMap(gMap);
  };

  const initSearchInput = () => {
    const searchInput = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(searchInputRef.current);
    searchInput.addListener('places_changed', () => {
      getPlaces = searchInput.getPlaces();
      const { formatted_address: address, geometry: { location, viewport } } = getPlaces[0];
      const boundBox = calcNESW(viewport);
      saveLocationSearch({
        address,
        boundBox,
        center: { lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() },
        zoom: 12,
      });
    });
  };

  const mapEvHandler = (gMap) => {
    const mapBounds = gMap.getBounds();
    const getCenter = gMap.getCenter();
    const getZoom = gMap.getZoom();
    const boundBox = calcNESW(mapBounds); // func returns NE & SW co-ords
    saveLocationSearch({
      address: `[${getCenter.lat()}, ${getCenter.lng()}]`,
      boundBox,
      zoom: getZoom,
      center: getCenter
    });
  };
```

How do I update the logic to not trigger `zoom-changed` handler unless the user triggers using the zoom controls. I feel like I am missing an important aspect of React Hooks `useEffect`.